# fastapi leaving Postgres idle connection

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, fastapi

I want to decrease the number of idle PostgreSQL requests coming in from fast-api calls. I am not able to figure out what exactly is leaving this many idle connections as multiple people are using this DB and APIs associated with it.

Can someone suggest what I might have done wrong to leave this many idle connections or an efficient way to figure out what is causing this so that I can accordingly fix that portion and decrease it somehow.

Not sure if I have provided sufficient information to explain this but if anything else is required, I will be more than happy to provide that information.

[postgresql idle connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lzDo.png)

This is how I am creating a PostgreSQL object via fastapi

```
class postgres:
    def __init__(self, config):
        try:
            SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://" + \
                config['postgresql']['user']+":"+config['postgresql']['password']+"@" + \
                config['postgresql']['host']+":5432" + \
                "/"+config['postgresql']['database']
            # print(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
            engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, future=True)
            self.SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
                autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine)
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def get_db(self):
        """
        Function to return session variable used by ORM
        :return: SessionLocal
        """
        try:
            db = self.SessionLocal()
            yield db
        finally:
            db.close()
```

Comment: Have you seen the SQLAlchemy pool configuration page? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html - and is there an actual issue with having idle connections? The point is that you save time when the connection needs to be established, so SQLAlchemy maintains a pool of available connections and reuse them if possible.

Comment: yeah, I saw that documentation. Even I tried one parameter, which I thought will reduce the number of connections (null pool). As per my understanding, it ensures that there is no pooling and in that case, it should open each request and close it (performance loss considered).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by the `get_db(self)`, as it creates (yields) a new connection/session object every time you call `SessionLocal()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that but I think that was not the issue as well. Cause the issue persists. I used following and it is still the same : ``` def get_session():
    """
    Function to return session variable used by ORM
    :return: SessionLocal
    """
    db = SessionLocal()
    return db ```